# How to get selected word when double-click on div, p, span?

Tags: javascript, html, selection, selection-api

Can you get the word the user has double-clicked on?  I've tried in a *onDblClick* eventhandler but *selectionStart* is undefined there; and the *onselect* event seems to be available only for TextArea.

Comment: The only way I've been able to do this is to wrap each and every  word in its own SPAN. Yahoo knows what word is highlighted when you right-click. And in IE, the accelerators know the highlighted word too. Are these connecting to the browser "below" the javascript/DOM layer, to some API?

Comment: That is, Yahoo Search on the context-menu in Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `document.selection.createRange().text` in IE, and `window.getSelection().toString()` in firefox and webkit, and attach to the `ondblclick` handler like so:

```
document.ondblclick = function () {
   var sel = (document.selection && document.selection.createRange().text) ||
             (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString());
   alert(sel);
};
```

**References**:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx), for `document.selection`
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection), for `window.getSelection()`

Answer (score 0):

[A Good answer by @David Tang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593104/9935654)

and `window.getSelection().toString()` is what I used.

---

I want to share that you can use `baseOffset` and `extentOffset` too.

```html
<p>test data.</p>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("dblclick", (e)=>{
    const selection = document.getSelection()
    // console.log(selection.anchorNode.data) // is whole text: "test data."
    const selectContent = selection.anchorNode.data.slice(selection.baseOffset, selection.extentOffset)
    console.log(selectContent)    
  })
</script>
```